# java MongoTemplate aggregate with project nested document

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document.

```
{
"errors" : [
    {
        "priority" : 3,
        "category" : "aaa"
        "other":"nothing"
    },
    {
        "priority" : 4,
        "category" : "bbb"
        "other":"nothing"
    },
    {
        "priority" : 2,
        "category" : "ccc"
        "other":"nothing"
    },
    {
        "priority" : 3,
        "category" : "ddd"
        "other":"nothing"
    },
    {
        "priority" : 2,
        "category" : "eee"
        "other":"nothing"
    }
    ],
"file_name" : "xxx.json",
"vehicle_id" : "esdf",
"day" : "2022-03-08"
}
```

I execute a command with js client.

```
db.wty_test.aggregate({
    $project: {
        '_id': 0, 'errors.priority': 1, 'errors.category': 1, 'file_name': 1, 'vehicle_id': 1,
    }
})
```

I get the result I want.[image]
The errors is an array containing objects.

Now I need to overwrite this command with java client(springboot-data-mongo).  This is my java code.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
...
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.project("errors.priority", "errors.category", "file_name", "vehicle_id"));
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "wty_test", HashMap.class).getMappedResults();
```

[image]
The priority and category is not in errors.

**How to use java to get the same result as js?**

I try the nested.But it's not what I want.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get the desired result.

```
Document projectn = new Document("$project", 
                        new Document("_id", 0L)
                        .append("file_name", 1L)
                        .append("vehicle_id", 1L)
                        .append("errors", 
                            new Document("$map", 
                                new Document("input", "$errors")
                                .append("in", 
                                    new Document("priority", "$$this.priority")
                                    .append("category", "$$this.category")
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    );

List<Document> pipeline = Arrays.asList(projectn);
List<Document> results = mongoOps.getCollection("collection_name")
                                 .aggregate(pipeline)
                                 .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Note that this uses MongoDB Java Driver API query syntax, and `Document` is `org.bson.Document`. The conversion of the native query to Java Driver uses `$map` aggregation array operator (and it looks like thats the (maybe only) way).

With `MongoTemplate.aggregate` the code is:

```
    Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            project() 
            .and( 
                VariableOperators.Map.itemsOf("errors")
                    .as("e")
                    .andApply(ctx -> new Document("priority", "$$e.priority").append("category", "$$e.category") ))
            .as("errors")
            .andExclude("_id")
            .andInclude("file_name", "vehicle_id")
    );

    AggregationResults<Document> results = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "collection_name", Document.class);
```

---

**Alternate Method:**

In case your query is just about the *projection*, you can use the following query using `MongoTemplate#find` method. This is much simpler to construct and understand:

```
db.collection.find(
    {}, // your query filter
    { _id: 0, 'errors.category': 1, 'errors.priority': 1, file_name: 1, vehicle_id: 1 }
)
```

The `MongoTemplate` version of it:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields()
     .include("errors.priority", "errors.category", "file_name", "vehicle_id")
     .exclude("_id");
List<Document> results = mongoOps.find(query, Document.class, "collection_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using the `nested()` function, like so:

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project("file_name", "vehicle_id").
    and("errors").nested(Fields.fields("priority","category"))

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(project);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I add the picture in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> projectFieldSet = Arrays.asList("errors.category","errors.priority");
List<Field> fieldList = projectFields.stream().map(f->{return Fields.field(f,f);}).collect(Collectors.toList());        
ProjectionOperation projectAggOp = Aggregation.project(Fields.from(fieldList.toArray(new Field[fieldList.size()])));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations!

Comment: This is a simple but effective solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597458/how-to-project-array-element-field-in-spring-data-mongo-db-aggregation